# STM32 Low power series microcontroller or STM32WL series with integrated LoRA? (IoT Device)

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, system-on-chip, iot

I'm starting a design of IoT device. Trouble that I have is deciding which setup to use. I would like to someone with more experience can point me to right direction. With everything that is happening with electronic components nowdays and long delivery time that also can be one of crucial reasons for selection of Microcontroller.
So since device will have a feature to work from battery, have battery management and charging from solar cell, it should be optimized with power consumption.
So would be better to have some STM32L series with external Semtech Lora chip or would it be better to have STM32WL series which have integrated sub-GHz radio on the chip?

Also I'm open to other MCU manufacturer if there is better alternative then STM32.

Comment: Define what "better" means to you? This might get closed due to being "what to buy" or "opinion-based" so can you make the question slightly more defined?

Comment: Unless the whole purpose of your device is to power up and do nothing, there are so many defining factors in component selection that this question, as written, is practically unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that power consumption is one of your concerns, one thought is that minimizing the number of power-consuming components may be helpful to meeting your goals.

An option to consider would be a low-power SoC with an integrated radio (an example of which is Microchip ATSAMR34), which would allow the micro direct control of the radio function for powering on/off when transmitting or receiving vs sleeping.

I'm sure there are many other requirements that you do not cite so obviously I can't speak to those.